# ffmpeg combine video downsampling and audio channel mapping

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video

I have two calls to ffmpeg which work when I use them separately in terminal. Now I'd like to combine both to one call but have no idea how. All my tests did fail so far.

```
ffmpeg -i in.mov -vf scale=1920:1080 -crf 20 -preset slow out.mp4

ffmpeg -i in.mov -filter_complex "[0:a]channelsplit=channel_layout=5.1[FL][FR][FC][LFE][BL][BR];[FL]anullsink;[FR]anullsink;[BL]anullsink;[BR]anullsink" -map 0:v -map "[FC]" -map "[LFE]" -vcodec copy -acodec pcm_s24le -ar 48000 -ac 1 out.mov
```

As I have more than 2 TB of media files which I'd like to convert with the combined ffmpeg command, a batch process reading all *.mov files within a defined folder and it's subfolders, converting and writing the output files to another defined folder would be great. The optimum would be when the file names, folder structure and folder names in the output folder would match the input folder.

I am working on Mac OSX

Comment: Might I suggest using [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr) instead? You can set parameters via gui, then save presets or batch the results. No typing required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a single command, you just have to combine the media operations,

`ffmpeg -i in.mov -filter_complex "[0:a]channelsplit=channel_layout=5.1[FL][FR][FC][LFE][BL][BR];[FL]anullsink;[FR]anullsink;[BL]anullsink;[BR]anullsink" -map 0:v -map "[FC]" -map "[LFE]" -vf scale=1920:1080 -crf 20 -preset slow -c:a pcm_s24le -ar 48000 -ac 1 out.mov`

Comment: Works well. I guess I had mixed some incompatible options and ffmpeg did not give me an error but was simply opening a new line in terminal with `=> `.